# module error not found on react

Tags: objective-c, react-native, rxjs

I'm following this [tutorial for RxJS](https://coursetro.com/courses/25/A-Comprehensive-RxJS-Tutorial---Learn-ReactiveX-for-JavaScript-)
but When I get to the part of setting up env, I get an error message when doing

> $yarn run start

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Observable";
console.log(Rx);
```

if I leave the log without the "Rx", it shows fine.
But if I use the log...  I get this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/Observable' in '/Users/manuel/Documents/testeos/JS/rxjs/node_modules/rxjs'
>    @ ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js 6:9-42
>    @ ./src/code.ts
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/code.ts

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: @ShoaibRaza yes thanks, yarn

Comment: Can you try to add `rxjs-compat` module - `yarn add rxjs-compat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today

Install `yarn add rxjs-compat` / `npm install rxjs-compat`

or

Do don't use deprecated imports: `rxjs/Rx`, `rxjs/Observable`, etc... ([see new import paths](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths))